# compare blocks and functions in objective C

Tags: objective-c, function, block

As I am learning objective C, my understanding is new and incomplete. The concept of a block is very similar to a function. They even look almost identical:

FUNCTION named 'multiply'

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int multiply (int x, int y)
{

    return x * y;

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {

        int result = multiply(7, 4); // Result is 28.
        NSLog(@"this is the result %u",result);

        }
}
```

BLOCK named 'Multiply'

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int (^Multiply)(int, int) = ^(int num1, int num2) {

    return num1 * num2;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    @autoreleasepool {

        int result = Multiply(7, 4); // Result is 28.
        NSLog(@"this is the result %u",result);
    }
}
```

I found various statements on the web like:
"Blocks are implemented as Objective-C objects, except they can be put on the stack, so they don't necessarily have to be malloc'd (if you retain a reference to a block, it will be copied onto the heap, though). "

Ray Wenderlich says:
"Blocks are first-class functions"

I have no clue what all this means. My example shows that the same thing is accomplished as a block or a function. Can someone show an example where blocks can do something functions cannot? or vice versa?
Or is it something more subtle, like the way the variable 'result' is handled in memory?
or is one faster/safer?
Can either of them be used as a method in a class definition?

Thank you.

Comment: Blocks are objects. Anything an object can do, blocks can as well. Including things like associating objects to them at runtime or adding them to collections.

Comment: A block is an anonymous function that in objective-c can be treated as an object. https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/featuredarticles/Short_Practical_Guide_Blocks/index.html

Comment: more importantly, block can capture values (i.e. it can be stableful) but function can't

Comment: @CrimsonChris - thank you for your examples but I do not know what 'associating objects at runtime' means or what collections are. Saying that blocks are like objects may be meaningful to you but i do not see how a function cannot be made to do the same thing.

Comment: @quellish - clearly you found the apple document from which i drew my example. but again that is like a circular reference since it does not mention how they differ from functions

Comment: Collections are things like dictionaries and arrays. You can read about associated objects here. http://nshipster.com/associated-objects/

Comment: @Bryan - thank you for your statement  but I do not understand what 'capturing values' means or even 'stableful' means. sorry i am learning this on my own and clearly lack some fundamental understanding of how a compiler operates.

Comment: I made a typo... I mean "stateful" not "stableful"... for capture values, you can google "closure"/"lambda", they are similar concept in various programming languages (javascript, python, c++, swift, ruby and many more)

Comment: @aquagremlin, that is because blocks ARE functions. They do not differ from functions. Because they are anonymous functions they can contain bindings to automatic or managed memory in the enclosing scope of their definition.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Blocks are Objective-C objects**, and functions aren't. In practice, this means you can pass around a block from one piece of code to another like so:

```
NSArray *names = @[@"Bob", @"Alice"];
[names enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id name, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    NSLog(@"Hello, %@", name);
}];
```

In C, you can achieve similar effects by passing around pointers to functions. The main difference between doing this and using blocks, however, is that **blocks can capture values.** For instance, in the example above, if we wanted to use a variable greeting:

```
NSString *greeting = @"Hello";
NSArray *names = @[@"Bob", @"Alice"];
[names enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id name, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    NSLog(@"%@, %@", greeting, name);
}];
```

In this example, the compiler can see that the block depends on the local variable `greeting` and will "capture" the value of `greeting` and store it along with the block (in this case, that means retaining and storing a pointer to an NSString). Wherever the block ends up getting used (in this case, within the implementation of `[NSArray -enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:]`), it will have access to the `greetings` variable as it was at the time the block was declared. **This lets you use any local variables in the scope of your block without having to worry about passing them into the block.**

To do the same using function pointers in C, `greeting` would have to be passed in as a variable. However, this can't happen because the caller (in this case, NSArray) can't know (especially at compile time) exactly which arguments it has to pass to your function. Even if it did, you'd need to somehow pass the value of `greeting` to NSArray, along with every other local variable you wanted to use, which would get hairy really quickly:

```
void greet(NSString *greeting, NSString *name) {
    NSLog(@"%@, %@", greeting, name);
}

// NSArray couldn't actually implement this
NSString *greeting = @"Hello";
NSArray *names = @[@"Bob", @"Alice"];
[names enumerateObjectsUsingFunction:greet withGreeting:greeting];
```

Comment: thank you igul222. I am so old that I remember basic and PL1 languages. In those, the variables in the main loop were usually accessible by subroutines, functions, or procedure calls(same thing as functions but nothing gets passed). Scope rules were paramount and you had to remember how many levels deep you were to know which variables were above you (accessible) and which were below you (not accessible).   It would seem

Comment: that blocks can therefore access any variable? Yes??  BTW, I try to add a line break to my comments but two spaces   at the end of a line does nothing. How do I make new paragraphs in these comments?

Answer (score 8):

Blocks are closures -- they can capture local variables from the surrounding scope. This is the big difference between blocks (and anonymous functions in other modern languages) and functions in C.

Here's an example of a higher-order function, `makeAdder`, which creates and returns an "adder", a function which adds a certain base number to its argument. This base number is set by the argument to `makeAdder`. So `makeAdder` can return different "adders" with different behavior:

```
typedef int (^IntFunc)(int);

IntFunc makeAdder(int x) {
    return ^(int y) { return x + y; }
}

IntFunc adder3 = makeAdder(3);
IntFund adder5 = makeAdder(5);

adder3(4); // returns 7
adder5(4); // returns 9
adder3(2); // returns 5
```

This would not be possible to do with function pointers in C, because each function pointer must point to an actual function in the code, of which there is a finite number fixed at compile time, and each function's behavior is fixed at compile time. So the ability to create a virtually unlimited number of potential "adders" depending on a value at runtime, like `makeAdder` does, is not possible. You would instead need to create a structure to hold the state.

A block which does not capture local variables from the surrounding scope, like in your example, is not much different from a plain function, aside from the type.